# Matlab: Simulate received signals of sonar sensors

Tags: matlab, mapping, sonar, exploration

StackExchange community!

I need the guidance what to use for the generation sensor data in Matlab. My purpose is to optimize the exploration process of unknown environment using the multi-robot system. For that, I need to simulate the sonar sensor signals. The question is how to simulate them in Matlab? 
I found [sensorsig module](https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/sensorsig.html) in Phased Array System Toolbox and the link to use [specialized ROS messages](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/work-with-specialized-ros-messages.html). Maybe, do you know some other solutions? 
The requirements to sensors are a) to know the frontier points b) to detect obstacles. The noise can be ignored.

Comment: You need to simulate the sonar sensor signals, but what exactly do you mean by that? How "low" are you looking to go in the simulation? Do you want simulated transducer output?

Comment: I would like to build a map in my matlab simulation. No needs to simulate the sound waves and clarify the speed of sound in the environment. Only to store the visible sensor regions through its motion. It means it's not important the sensor type.. Thank you for ur question.  It helped me to determine what I should do :))

Comment: I'm going to close this question as an open-ended design question. If you don't need actual transducer output then really you're just looking for something that is generating a map given a particular location and sensor orientation. The most simplified version of this is [ray casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting). You can do this in Matlab with something like the [Moller-Trumbore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möller–Trumbore_intersection_algorithm) to check for intersections with a triangle and then a world that's built in CAD, etc. and exported as an STL object.

Comment: That's just one way to do it, though - a lot of this depends on your project, your current formats, how detailed you want to get with your simulation, etc. This really is a design project and questions like this are best asked in [chat]. If you continue with the project and have a more specific question (debugging, troubleshooting, algorithm implementation, etc.) please come back and ask those questions here.